# Arrow functions using call, apply, bind - not working?

Tags: javascript, binding, ecmascript-6, this

I'm being a bit puzzled when I try to convert a simple ES5 code to ES6.

Let's say I have this block of code:

```
var obj = {num: 2}

var addToThis = function (a, b, c) {
  return this.num + a + b + c
}

// call
console.log(addToThis.call(obj, 1, 2, 3))

// apply
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(addToThis.apply(obj, arr))

// bind
const bound = addToThis.bind(obj)
console.log(bound(1, 2, 3))
```

Everything above runs smoothly and as expected.

But as soon as I start using ES6 features such as const and arrow function, like this:

```
const obj = {num: 2}

const addToThis = (a, b, c) => {
  return this.num + a + b + c
}
```

It doesn't work anymore and throws an error: Cannot read property 'num' of undefined.

Can someone please explain why `this` doesn't work anymore?

Comment: hey @angular_learner did you get the necessary answer to your question here? If no can you please point out then it would be easier for others to provide a more detailed answer, if yes then please mark it as accepted. Will be helpful for many

Comment: The answer is not sufficient

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lambda functions (arrow functions) doesn't create new functional context and use context of a calling function.

So "this" refers to a parent context. If there's no 'num' variable than it's undefined.

Usually it's really convenient because most of the time you use one context instead of creating a new one in every function you create. In my opinion call/apply/bind is completely confusing and lambda functions makes it unnecessary.