# How to bind 'this' into object using arrow function

Tags: javascript

I need to bind this keyword inside object using arrow function. Is it possible?

Please don't mark this as duplicate because I have read 10 articles about this here in stackoverflow and I haven't found answer yet. I'm just curious if this is possible because everywhere is just workaround without using arrow function.

This is what I have tried without success.

```js
const person1 = {
  name: 'Dude',
  showName: function(){
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}

const person2 = {
  name: 'Dude',
  showName(){
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}

const person3 = {
  name: 'Dude',
  showName: () => {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}

const person4 = {
  name: 'Dude',
  showName: (() => {
    console.log(this.name)
  }).bind(this)
}

/* const person5 = {
  name: 'Dude',
  showName: () => {
    console.log(this.name)
  }.bind(this)
} */

person1.showName() // Dude
person2.showName() // Dude
person3.showName() // result
person4.showName() // result
// person5.showName() // SyntaxError
```

Comment: create a class. theres no way to override what's `this` in arrow functions.

Comment: just use a normal function.  stop creating problems that don't need to exist

Comment: arrow functions are not mandatory in ES6

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was just curious if it is posibble, if I'm missing anything.

Comment: I'm sure this has been covered before. Did you not find an answer or just not find an answer that you liked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you bind arrow functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-arrow-functions) and [JavaScript binding - arrow functions and bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630044) and [Arrow functions using call, apply, bind - not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576089)

Comment: @adiga That is a better duplicate target than the one I picked. In either case, it is a clear duplicate.

Comment: To further try to explain the potential fustration with this question.  Imagine you have a box.  It's green.  It's existed for a long time.  Then someone makes a new box, and it's yellow!  And you say, hey, that's pretty cool, I want to use that box..... but I want it to be green.  There is a very simple solution to that "issue".

Comment: @Taplar A better analogy might be if the yellow box had some very cool features which were seemingly independent of the color but which the green box lacked.

Comment: It's not a perfect analogy, but I think it makes the point, :)

Comment: @Taplar No analogy is perfect, and I agree that yours effectively makes an important point.